# How to add module in AngularJS ngBoilerplate?

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

I'm using AngularJS [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) and trying to add my module. I placed file mymodule/mymodule.js with code 
`angular.module( 'mymodule', [] );` 
in [common](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.2-release/src/common) directory. I added path to file in [build.config.js](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/build.config.js), then add it to [app.js](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/src/app/app.js) dependencies:

```
angular.module('app', [ ..., 'mymodule'
```

then run `grunt build` and got:

```
Iceweasel 24.7.0 (Linux 0.0.0) AppCtrl isCurrentUrl should pass a dummy test 1 FAILED
minErr/<@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:68
loadModules/<@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:4379
forEach@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:336
loadModules@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:4339
createInjector@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:4265
workFn@/var/www/angular/vendor/bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409
```

script mymodule.js included in page correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer! Adding path mask for my module to [karma-unit.tpl.js](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.2-release/karma/karma-unit.tpl.js) solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to place the nodule in the common directory ? I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve. However, to get up and running with a custom module in ngbp, I would suggest that you create a new folder under [src/app](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.2-release/src/app) called mymodule. Next create a mymodule.js under the newly created directory. Finally, add your code to the file:

```
angular.module( 'mymodule', [
    ....
]);
```

And add the module to the src/app/app.js

```
angular.module('app', [ ..., 'mymodule']);
```

The grunt build should be working at this stage.

Comment: Thank you for answer! According readme: The src/common/ directory houses internal and third-party re-usable components. Essentially, this folder is for everything that isn't completely specific to this application. -That's what I want, add re-usable component.

Comment: Ah! I thought you had a specific reason for using the src/common directory. Glad you found your answer.